# Codeigniter 3.1.11 unable to open welcome page

Tags: codeigniter

1. I have downloaded and  using  Codeigniter 3.1.11.
2. I have copied the same  to  as usual htdoc folder.
3. Tomcat is  Binary Installed and  service running and able to get
   the Welcome page  with `http://localhost/CodeIgniter3111/index.php/welcome`.
4. I have  inserted  in .htaccess  as below.

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css uploads|fevicon.png)
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ais=([a-z0-9-_]+)
   RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
   RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
   RewriteBase /CodeIgniter3111/
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
   ```
5. and also removed the index.php from Config.
6. `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/CodeIgniter3111';` and added the base url as well.
7. As I type in url (`http://localhost/CodeIgniter3111/welcome`), I am
   getting  below error in browser.

   > Not Found
   >
   > The requested URL /CodeIgniter3111/welcome was not found on this server.

I appreciate  support in advance.

Comment: is the rewrite mode on in your Apache server ?

Answer (score 0):

$config['base_url'] = 'https://localhost:8888/Your folder name';

your port number should be there